# buildLibsFromSource - what is it about?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I migrated to nx version 14.1.9 and now I have the [buildLibsFromSource](https://nx.dev/packages/angular/executors/webpack-browser#buildlibsfromsource) setting in my project.json; but I don't actually understand why I should use it or when and the [documentation](https://nx.dev/packages/angular/executors/webpack-browser#buildlibsfromsource) is limited.

As the default value is normally true, there is probably a good reason to use it. The migration set it to false.

But setting it to true, doesn't that kill the caching feature of nx? Because that is one main reason to make a library buildable, right?

Answer (score 0):

One thing we learned the hard way was this property stops Tailwind from working if set to true. The CSS pre-processors that are configured per module don't kick in and as a result, no CSS is created. This goes for serve and build targets.

This is not an answer. Just an observation from lessons learned in production.